# How to set the input mode for each application in OS X

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, input-languages

On OS X Mavericks, is there a way how to fix the input mode on each application?

I use two languages to work such google search in Japanese and English, and Android development (English only). So, I have to change the input mode frequently and the key response is not so fast.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried the Auto-switching in Keyboard Preferences?

This is maybe not optimal, but worths trying.

[image: Input Sources]

Comment: Thank you for telling me. It worked with multiple chrome window and gave me nice idea in this picture which is multiple input source.